# How to structure my class objects for an online chat room?

Tags: java

I want to design an online chat room using `web-sockets`. The three classes I will be creating objects from are **Room**, **User**, and **Message**.

I am wondering how to structure my code.

I am assuming Room 'has-a' relationship with both User and Message.
, since the room will have multiple users and messages.

> And I assume User 'has-a' relationship with Message. Does this
>   relationship need to exist if the program will never ask for messages
>   sent by a specific user?

With Message having no relationship.

```java
public class Room {
    String id;

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    public Room(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```java
public class User {

    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    String firstName, surname;
    int phone;

    public User(String f, String s, int p){
        this.firstName = f;
        this.surname = s;
        this.phone = p;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Message {
    String content, author;

    public Message(String m, String a){
        this.content = m;
                this.author = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is probably a good candidate for code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I suggest designing this starting with the methods, not the classes. By which I mean, start by thinking about what the program *does*, not what it *is*.